# Why do detectives Regan and Baker wear the "08" precinct number if they're not from there?

Tags: blue-bloods

In the TV show *Blue Bloods*, the characters of Det. Regan and Det. Baker wear "08" insignia on their dress uniforms denoting the precinct they belong to.

Is there a canon or real-world NYPD explanation for this? Det. Regan belongs to the 54 and Det. Baker is assigned to the Commissioner at 1PP. Seeing as neither belongs to the 8th precinct, I was wondering why they wear that insignia on their uniform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a closer look (and some binge watching), I came to realize the collar brass doesn't say "08", but "DB" for detective bureau, which makes sense.